# Импорт модулей прямо в функцию или class :python

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт

```py
def drive_list_func():
    from win32api import GetLogicalDriveStrings

    return GetLogicalDriveStrings()
```

Можно ли таким образом импортировать модуль прямо в функцию и не по говнокодерски ли это?
Так как это достаточно удобно, ведь он (как я понял) удаляется из памяти после использования функции.

Comment: Так делать неправильно. [import_module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib)

Comment: @And Если не врать, я мало что могу понять из это документации. Можно подробнее пожалуйста?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> «Можно ли таким образом импортировать модуль прямо в функцию и не по говнокодерски ли это?»

Можно, но это по «говнокодерски», как вы правильно сказали.
См. *«PEP 8 - руководство по написанию кода на Python»,* часть [Импорты](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#id8):

> Импорты всегда помещаются в начале файла, сразу после комментариев к модулю и строк документации, и перед объявлением констант.

---

> «... ведь он (как я понял) удаляется из памяти после использования функции.»

Вы абсолютно прав.
Но оно того не стоит.

Потому что смысл для импорта модуля нет в том, чтоб он что-то **делал** — хорошо написанный модуль не делает ничего кроме **определений** функций, классов и переменных-констант.

Значит, он сам *не использует много памяти (скажем, 1 KB для 100 строк кода),* потому что он сам **не вызывает** эти функции и **не создает** объекты этих классов.

(Значит, какая-то *маленькая* память после импорта использована, но пока вы не вызовете импортованую функцию или не создаете объекты, *никакой дополнительной памяти не нужно.*)

Потому

- команды `import` пишутся в начале программы (модуля) — память **не освобождается,**
- функции / классы используются *внутри функций* — после окончания вызванной функции память **освобождается**.

Answer (score 3):

Так делать можно, но от этого нет пользы, а в придачу вам за такое руки поотбивают. :)